# Consuming an Outbound Message using Apex within Salesforce

Tags: apex, soap-api, workflowoutboundmessage

My issue is pretty straight forward :

I have a workflow rule which fires on insert and sends an out bound message.

I am looking for a way to consume that out bound message in sales force itself by creating a SOAP web service or by any other means(I want to avoid using a third party system/server in between as a bridge to SOAP and rest).

Is there a way to do this?
Please guide, examples appreciated.

Thanks!!!

Comment: Are you trying to integrate data from one Salesforce Org to another? If so, you may be better served by something like Salesforce to Salesforce or a direct Callout from Apex. The issue with using outbound messages will be accepting the incoming request in Salesforce. The outbound message won't have session details for the target org. You would need to make a public web service to receive the message.

Comment: The reason I want this is, when ever say a lead is inserted I want to send the details to another system via a REST callout, since callouts are not allowed in triggers (@future doesn't fit the bill) the best way would be by an outbound message. So if I create a Salesforce site and expose a SOAP service on that URL I would just need to worry about accepting the outbound message, get the id in the message and make the REST callout using the data.

Comment: Is the other system a Salesforce Org, or just a REST web service? I suspect a REST callout from an @future method of a queue table with a scheduled job will be a lot easier to implement and maintain.

Comment: The other system is a REST service. I have taken that path by running an apex job from a trigger which induces a time delay that cannot be predicted and is inconsistent, for a mission critical requirement we need to know if the request failed/succeeded with minimum time delay so after digging a little this seems to be the fastest option. So is there any way to consume the outbound message by creating an apex SOAP service?

Comment: The outbound message is essentially [async as well](https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=workflow_tracking_outbound_message_delivery_status.htm&language=en_US) and has it's own separate processing queue. I doubt you will see better performance from such an approach. If you don't won't to make your own async queue, maybe see if you can get on the [FlexQueue pilot](https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/engineering/2014/05/flex-batch-apex-muscles-flexqueue.html?language=en).

Comment: I have deployed such an approach earlier in a different system but with dependency on a different service to accept the outbound message, read the data and make a REST call back to salesforce with the required data. So to eliminate the dependency on a 3rd party system to essentially convert  SOAP to REST I wanted to try this approach to. Though FlexQueue seems promising(Thanks for sharing it will be of immense use.), as of now I want to try this first. Any guidance in this direction is appricated. Thanks.

Comment: Hi I have similar requirement , can you give your input here. I need to invoke Apex Class using Outbound message in Apex . I have Webservice Apex class which creats attachment as a PDF returned from a VF Page. I want to invoke this class through a outbound message , is there any way how I can do that? I tried pointing URL of the Apex Class WSDL as endpoint in the outbound message but it did not work or got invoked ? Can someone give their input on this?

Comment: Related [Workflow Outbound Message to Salesforce Web Service](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/q/48822/102).